# GDB in DDD on Assembly .asm file won't allow me to look up variable value

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, ubuntu-22.04, ddd-debugger

I've been trying to look up a value using gdb in ddd but when I type `x/uw &min` at the prompt I just get a return character that resembles a logic negation simple that has been tilted upward ninety degrees.

My computer is an Evolve III maestro and my operating system is linux amd 64 architecture Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I've tried looking at keyboard settings and making sure they're standard to US settings. I really need this debugger to work properly so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're not actually *typing* the `(gdb) ` part, are you?  That's the GDB prompt for command-line GDB.  The GDB command is just the `x /uw`, with `&min` as the operand (the address to dump an unsigned 32-bit word from)

Comment: @peter no, I didn’t type Gdb and yes I’m trying to see the value of an unsigned double word variable

Comment: Ok then yeah, seems weird, possible DDD bug.  Does it help to choose a name other than `min`?  It should still be hex-dumping some memory, though, even if it's the wrong memory (e.g. a symbol of the same name somewhere in libc can sometimes be what GDB picks.)  I assume the GDB command works fine in command-line `gdb`.

Comment: @peter if I choose any other variable, the same return character is produced in Gdb. Yes, Gdb works just fine in the command-line.